# How to import PyQGIS to standalone Python on Linux virtual environment?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I have a standalone script, to which I'd like to use functionalities of PyQGIS. I am using virtual environment for the whole project. Because PyQGIS is not available via `pip` I am trying to find a workaround.

Of course, I looked into PyQGIS Cookbook where I found important info:

> You need to tell your system where to search for QGIS libraries and appropriate Python modules if they are not in
> a well-known location - otherwise Python will complain:
> `import qgis.core`
> `ImportError: No module named qgis.core`

> This can be fixed by setting the PYTHONPATH environment variable. In the following commands, **qgispath** should be replaced with your actual QGIS installation path:
> • on Linux: export PYTHONPATH=/**qgispath**/share/qgis/python
> Now, the path to the PyQGIS modules is known, but they depend on the qgis_core and qgis_gui libraries
> (the Python modules serve only as wrappers). The path to these libraries may be unknown to the operating system,
> and then you will get an import error again (the message might vary depending on the system):
> `import qgis.core`
> `ImportError: libqgis_core.so.3.2.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

> Fix this by adding the directories where the QGIS libraries reside to the search path of the dynamic linker:
> • on Linux: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/**qgispath**/lib

The problem is, either I do not know where my **qgispath** is (I tried multiple different paths within my filesystem) or I am doing something else entirely wrong.

Comment: Where did you install qgis?

Comment: you can find your qgis path by running "which qgis" in the command line.

Comment: @IanTurton @JanPisl  `which qgis` restuls in /usr/bin/qgis and that is the binary, innit? I'm supposing this is not what I'm searching for as the PYTHONPATH requires some Python library. Not sure though.

Comment: Installing Qgis on Ubuntu from the [qgis.org](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu) repo puts all the python stuff in the system site packages directory (`/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`), so create your virtualenv with `--system-site-packages` then [install any specific requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19459977/737471) to your virtual env

Comment: @user2856 Yes, I've also reached this path and solution during my search but could not break/recreate my current virtualenv. As soon as I can I will try this and get back with the result.